# Which of the two popular definitions of independent events is more primitive?

Tags: probability, bayesian

I know there are two ways to say event $a$ and $b$ are independent:

- $P(a)P(b)=P(a\cap b)$
- $P(a\mid b)=P(a)$

and I can derive one from the other with the Bayes Formula $P(a|b)=P(a\cap b)/P(b)$.
My question is: Of the two equations above, which is the definition from which the other equation is proven?

Comment: Interesting question! But, doesn`t this depend on the case, when you are using the formula? Whats do you want to achieve with this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days searching, I find it's clearly explained in the [wiki pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29):

> Two events A and B are independent if and only if their joint
>   probability equals the product of their probabilities:
>
> $P(A∩B)=P(A)P(B) $
>
> Why this defines independence is made clear by rewriting with
>   conditional probabilities: [image: conditional probabilities]
>
> Although the derived expressions may seem more intuitive, they are not
>   the preferred definition, as **the conditional probabilities may be
>   undefined if $P(A)$ or $P(B)$ are 0**. Furthermore, the preferred
>   definition **makes clear by symmetry** that when $A$ is independent of
>   $B$, $B$ is also independent of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If my primitive you mean immediately apparent, and obvious I would say $$P(a)*P(b)=P(ab)$$ but this might be considered subjective, although in practice, that equation *is* where almost all probability classes start. It is quite intuitively obvious, although to a prodigy Baye's theorem might be "obvious" as well.

Comment: To me, the intuitive definition of independence is saying "the probability of $a$ does not change if $b$ occurs or not", which directly means $P(a|b)=P(a)$. If I think of real life random events, I normally use that to determine whether events are independent, and then use Bayes formula to get $P(a)P(b)=P(ab)$. But in probability theory, it is common to define independence by $P(a)P(b)=P(ab)$; that's a simpler formula mathematically and it is easier to build from that.

Comment: @JiK yes it *is* common to define independence by $P(a)P(b) =P(ab)$ which is intuitive too. But $P(a|b)=P(a)$ is intuitive as well. It is through this combined intuition that you understand Baye's theorem. You do not need to take it for granted.

Answer (score 0):

I've most often seen $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ as the *definition* of independence, and for independent events $A,B$, $P(A|B)=P(A)$ as a theorem that one proves using the previous definition. So in that sense $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ is as "primitive" as it gets.