# How do Regular Conditional Probabilities assign values to $P(A|B)$ when $P(B) = 0$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Yeah, like in the title, how do Regular Conditional Probabilities assign values to $P(A|B)$ when $P(B) = 0$? Because I am not trained in advanced probability, please explain it as simply as possible. It'll be great if you can demonstrate with an example. Let $X$ be a random variable between $[0, 1]$. What is the $P(X=\frac{2}{3}|X=\frac{2}{3})$?

Also, can it also assign values to $P(A|B)$ in finite spaces? For example, imagine you throw a die, and you observe that the die landed on an odd number at 12 noon. So letting $O$ be the event that the die landed odd, $P(O)$ changes from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $1$ after noon. Hence, after noon, letting $E$ be the event that the die landed even, $P(E)$ changes to $0$. But even after 12 noon, I still intuitively want to say that $P(E|E)$ is still $1$. It seems to me that for any non-empty set $A$ in the sigma-algebra, $P(A|A) = 1$. Can regular conditional probabilities assign $P(E|E)$  a value of $1$? Is it possible? Or do I need to give that intuition up? Thanks for your help.

Edit: I think my question is different from this: [Probability, conditional on a zero probability event](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110112/probability-conditional-on-a-zero-probability-event)

Because I'm asking about finite spaces too. Also, I'm asking for a demonstration of how regular conditional probabilities assign value to $P(X=\frac{2}{3}|X=\frac{2}{3})$.

Edit 2: Let the sample space in the dice example be {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.

Edit 3: The sample space for the dice example is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. The initial probability function before noon is $P$. After noon, the probability function becomes $P'$. So $P(O)$ = $P(E)$ = 0.5. But $P'(O) = 1$ and $P'(E) = 0$. Still, I want to say that $P'(E|E) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition behind $P(A|B)$ is 
"what is the probability of $A$ if I know that $B$ happened?"

When $P(B)=0$ the event $B$ can't happen, so the conditional probability of $A$ is undefined.

The same intuition explains why $P(E|E) = 1$.

In your example with a die and a clock you have to be careful to specify the sample space. There are really twelve events, not six: each possible value of the throw and the information about whether the time is before or after noon. If you make that explicit no probabilities "change".

**Edit** in response to comments (and downvotes).

The question asks about intuition, particularly for a finite sample space. When throwing a die, there are no nonempty events with probability $0$. That is still true when the throw is before or after noon (as a binary choice). A typical one of the $12$ atomic events is ($3$, before noon).

The situation is indeed subtler for continuous distributions. In the mathematical model a throw "exactly at noon" is a nonempty event with probability $0$. In the physical world no  experiment can determine whether something happens exactly at noon, only approximately at noon up to some measurement uncertainty.

Comment: "When $P(B)=0$ the event $B$ can't happen, so the conditional probability of $A$ is undefined." The OP is talking about regular versions, and this explanation is misleading in that context. Think of something like this: $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and then $Y$ is a Bernoulli variable with success probability $X$. An expression like $P(Y=1|X=p)$ is definitely meaningful, even though the condition has probability $0$.

Comment: When $P(B)=0$ the event $B$ is a null event, an *almost* impossible event that *almost* never occurs.  This does not mean that it can never occur however.  Do not confuse $P(B)=0$ with $B=\emptyset$, these are different non-equivalent statements.  The example in the linked question of if $X,Y$ are continuous random variables independently and uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, you have $Pr(X=0.5)=0$ but $Pr(X+Y>1\mid X=0.5)$ is clearly equal to $0.5$.

Comment: Okay, point taken about the sample space. Let the sample space be ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for a single event $B$ of probability zero, there is no definition (not even "regular conditional probability") for $P(A|B)$.

However, when $X$ is a random variable, there is a definition for $P(A|X=t)$ that holds for "almost all $t$" even if $P(X=t)= 0$ or all $t$.  In some cases, this is a continuous function of $t$, and then we can by convention use the "continuous version" to get $P(A|X=t)$ for all $t$.

More generally, when $\mathcal F$ is a sigma-algebra, there is a definition for $P(A|\mathcal F)$, which is a random variable and thus defined only up to sets of measure zero.

I say "more generally" because the case $P(A|X=t)$ is obtained when we use the sigma-agebra $\sigma(X)$ generated by $X$.

Comment: Pardon me if I'm dense, but when you say "single event", do you mean an event in a finite space? Like landing on 1 when a die is tossed?

Comment: I mean: we can define $P(A|B)$ in certain cases where we define it for lots of sets $B$ at once.  But not when we define it for only one set $B$ of probability zero.