# Expectation of a CDF of a random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation, cumulative-distribution-functions

I was trying to solve the following exercise problem from Hogg, McKean and Craig's "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics".

**3.4.28.** For $Z$ distributed $N(0,1)$, it can be shown that $E[\Phi(hZ + k)] = \Phi[{k}/{\sqrt{1 + h^2}}]$ ...

Here, $\Phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ stand for cdf and pdf of $N(0,1)$.

That is just part of the exercise. In order to prove it, I tried expanding it as a double integral and ran out of steam. Answers on SE threads seem to make use of the following claim

$$E[\Phi(hZ + k)] = P(X \leq (hZ + k)),$$ where $X$ is also $N(0,1)$.

Among bazillion threads which make use of this claim and present the rest of the trivial details of the proof as to why  $E[\Phi(hZ + k)] = \Phi[{k}/{\sqrt{1 + h^2}}]$ (or something equivalent) is true, [this is one such answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/135405/135384).

Why is this true? Is it a trivial result or is there quite a bit of proving involved to assert that $$E[\Phi(hZ + k)] = P(X \leq (hZ + k))?$$

**This is what I know:** It is known that $\Phi(hz + k) = P(X \leq (hz+k)) $ so that $ \Phi(hZ + k)\rvert_{Z=z} = P(X \leq (hz + k)).$ So is it that by applying the so-called law of total probability as was done [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61098/183497), we can simply conclude that $$P(X \leq (hZ + k)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X \leq (hZ + k))|_{Z=z}\phi(z)dz \\ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(hz + k)\phi(z)dz \\ = E[\Phi(hZ + k)]?$$

Please let me know.

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me. You always have to be a little bit careful conditioning on an event of probability zero such as {Z=z}, though it turns out in cases like yours it's fine as long as you're doing it "underneath an integral sign". You could see [here][1] for some more discussion, though from a more applied perspective it's sufficient to just remember to work underneath an integral sign when conditioning on continuous random variables.


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074255/zero-probability-condition-thinking-about-ph-int-b-in-mathbb-rphb-b?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks @Red5551 for the reference thread. I will eventually dig into measure theoretic foundations of probability. Right now, I am simply looking at "mathematical statistics" which, at least in this book I am studying from, seems to lack rigor at certain points and that really bothers me a lot. Thanks a bunch once again for the valuable feedback.